# Save file list into text file using python

Tags: python, list, file, split, save

I would like to get the file name without its extension/suffix with split with specific character.

There are so many jpg files in directory.

for example,

> A_list(B)_001.jpg
>
> Stack_overflow_question_0.3.jpg
>
> ... and hundreds files in some directory

what I want is to get just the file NAMES without their extensions, like:

> A_list(B), 001
>
> Stack_overflow_question, 0.3

but with below code,

```
import os

path = 'D:\HeadFirstPython\chapter3'
os.chdir(path)

data = open('temp.txt', 'w')

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        file = file.split('_')
        print(file, file=data)

data.close()
```

I got like below result.

> ['A', 'list(B)', '001.jpg']
>
> ['Stack', 'overflow', 'question', '0.3.jpg']

Can this be done with less code?

Thanks and kind regards, 
Tim

Comment: That isn't very much code as it is...

Comment: do you want a list of lists or individual lists?

Comment: I need individual lists :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import glob
import os

path = 'D:\HeadFirstPython\chapter3'
os.chdir(path)
with open("temp.txt","w") as f: # with automatically closes your files
   my_l = [x.replace(".jpg","").rsplit("_",1) for x in glob.glob("*.jpg")] # list of lists



with open("temp.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        print x.replace(".jpg", "").rsplit("_", 1) # each list
```

The output will look like:

```
s = "Stack_overflow_question_0.3.jpg"

print s.replace(".jpg", "").rsplit("_", 1)
['Stack_overflow_question', '0.3']
```

To write to txt file without `","`:

```
with open("temp.txt", "w") as f:  # with automatically closes your files
    my_l = [x.replace(".jpg", "").rsplit("_", 1) for x in glob.glob("*.jpg")]
    for l in my_l:
        f.write(str(l).replace(",", ""))
```

Using `"*.jpg"` will search for any file ending with `jpg`. `rsplit("_",1)` will split on the rightmost `_` and using `1` as `maxsplit` will only split once. We simply replace the extension with `str.replace`.

Comment: Can I ask you something to save result into text file? When I save it, Its form is "list" so it contains [ ' , ] like these 4 characters. How can I remove these?

Comment: what do you want to do with the contents of the txt file later?

Comment: I use an external app which is developed with LISP language. I want to make a script with python based on file name and send it to the external app.

Comment: @user3880099, the last part of the answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
if file.endswith('.jpg'):
        file = file.rsplit('_',1)
        print file[0],
        print file[1].rsplit('.',1)[0]
        print(file, file=data)
```